# Why is Python 3 TCP Client not closing connection?

Tags: python, sockets, connection

I want to close client connections in a simple client-server-chat in the right way without timing out connection to close them. Unfortunately connection on client site is not closing.

Server Code

```py
import socket
import sys

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_address = ('localhost', 65432)
sock.bind(server_address)
sock.listen(1)

while True:
    connection, client_address = sock.accept()
    try:
        while True:
            data = connection.recv(1024)
            print(data)
            if data:
                connection.sendall(data)
            else:
                break

    finally:
        connection.close()
```

Client Code

```py
import socket
import time

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 65432

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
s.sendall(b'Hello world')

data = s.recv(1024)
print('Received', data)
time.sleep(5)
#s.sendall('Hello world, again'.encode())
s.close()
```

Starting server results in:

```
tcp    LISTEN   0    1    127.0.0.1:65432    0.0.0.0:*
```

After running client I expected the same state, but client connection is open.

```
tcp   LISTEN    0    1   127.0.0.1:65432    0.0.0.0:*                  
tcp   TIME-WAIT   0    0    127.0.0.1:57794    127.0.0.1:65432
```

BUT if I uncomment following line:

```py
#s.sendall('Hello world, again'.encode())
```

The result is as I expected.

```
tcp    LISTEN   0    1    127.0.0.1:65432    0.0.0.0:*
```

**Why is connection instantly closed with a second data send and timed out without?**

Answer (score 1):

TCP is a reliable protocol.  Even if a client sends data and closes the connection, the connection is maintained for a period of time in case data packets need to be re-transmitted.  The `TIME_WAIT` will go away after a few minutes.  There is an option `SO_LINGER` that can control the timeout.

Comment: This answers not the question, connection is instantly closed by sending two messages wihtout protocol timeout.

Comment: @gogan When I tested your code, when the 2nd message was sent and the client closed the connection without receiving the response from the server, the server raised a connectionAbortedError, so it didn't go back to a `LISTEN`...it just stopped.  That would instantly close the connection, I guess :^)

Comment: I get no error messages, maybe it depends on python version. I use 3.7. After I run client script, connection is instantly closed with second message and server is in listening state. on both sides, there is no open connection. A "connectionAbortedError" will be result in a tcp timeout on the other side and not in closing connection on both sides.